# 2 different inherited class overwrites

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have to work on an ANSI project and it requires some 2D arrays. I have 2 derived class of a base class (the base class is a 2D-Object array). When I attempt to add the smaller (shape) array into the bigger (map) array, it overwrites my dimensions for the bigger array.

**Code:**

**Base Class**

```
public class pixelGrid
{
    private static pixelCell[][] bitMap;
    private static pixelCell defaultCell;

    public pixelGrid()
    {
        defaultCell = new pixelCell();
    }

    public pixelGrid(int width, int height)
    {
        bitMap = new pixelCell[width][height];
        defaultCell = new pixelCell();
    }

    public static void setDimension(int width, int height)
    {
        bitMap = new pixelCell[width][height];
    }

    //...
}
```

**Smaller Grid:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class shape extends pixelGrid
{
public String name;
private static boolean hasDimension;
private static boolean hasDefaultCell;
public shape(String n)
{
    name = n;
    hasDimension = false;
    hasDefaultCell = false;
    draw(); 
}

public void draw()
{
    try(Scanner parser = new Scanner(new File (name +".cmd")))
    {
        String commandToken = parser.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Line(shape): " + commandToken);
        while(commandToken.charAt(0) != 'q')
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(commandToken);
            String commandLine = sc.next();
            System.out.println("command(shape):" + commandLine);
            if(commandLine.equals("d") && !hasDimension)
            {
                setDimension(commandToken);
                hasDimension = true;
            }
            else if(commandLine.equals("b") && !hasDefaultCell)
            {
                setDefaultCell(commandToken);
                hasDefaultCell = true;
            }
            else if(hasDimension && hasDefaultCell)
            {
                char command = commandToken.charAt(0);
                switch(command)
                {
                    case 'l':
                    drawLine(commandToken);
                    break;
                    case 'c':
                    drawCircle(commandToken);
                    break;
                    case 'p':
                    drawPoint(commandToken);
                    break;
                    case 'e':
                    erase(commandToken);
                    break;
                    case 'x':
                    ANSI.cls();
                    break;
                    default:
                    commandToken = parser.nextLine();
                    break;
                }
            }
            commandToken = parser.nextLine();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println( "\nError reading input file(from shape): " + name);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    private static void setDefaultCell(String command)
    {
        Scanner parser = new Scanner(command);
        parser.next();
        String token = parser.next();
        char c;
        if(token.equals("space"))
        {
            c = ' ';
        }
        else
        {
            c = token.charAt(0);
        }
        int fg = ANSI.color2Int(parser.next());
        int bg = ANSI.color2Int(parser.next());
        parser.close();
        pixelCell cell = new pixelCell(c,fg,bg);
        setDefaultCell(cell);
        clearMap(getDefaultCell());
        System.out.println("Default Cell: " + getDefaultCell());
    }

    private static void setDimension(String command)
    {
        Scanner parser = new Scanner(command);
        System.out.println("command(shape): " + command);
        parser.next();
        int w = parser.nextInt();
        int h = parser.nextInt();
        setDimension(w,h);
        System.out.println("Dimensions: " + getWidth() + " x " + getHeight());
    }

//...

}
```

**Bigger Grid**

```
public class bitMap extends pixelGrid
{

    public bitMap(int width, int height)
    {
        super(width, height);
    }

    public void addShape(int x, int y, shape s)
    {
        int shapeX = 0;
        int shapeY = 0;
        System.out.println("Dimensions(map): " + getWidth() + " x " + getHeight());
        System.out.println("Dim(shape): " + x + " , " + y + " " + s.getWidth() + " x " + s.getHeight());
        for(int w = x; w < (x + s.getWidth()); w++)
        {
            for(int h = y; h < (y + s.getHeight()); h++)
            {
                setCell(w,h,s.getCell(shapeX,shapeY));
                shapeY++;
            }
            shapeX++;
            shapeY = 0;
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

**Debug results:**

> Dimensions(Map > pre-shape-proc): 200 x 100
>
> Line(shape): d 10 10
>
> command(shape):d
>
> command(shape): d 10 10
>
> Dimensions: 10 x 10
>
> Dimensions(map > after-shape-creation): 10 x 10

**Edit:**

here is my main method:

**Main:**

```
public class project2
{
    private static bitMap map;
    private static boolean hasDimension;
    private static boolean hasDefaultCell;
    public project2()
    {
        hasDimension = false;
        hasDefaultCell = false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try(Scanner parser = new Scanner(new File(args[0])))
        {
            String commandToken = parser.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Line: " + commandToken);
            while (commandToken.charAt(0) != 'q' )
            {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(commandToken);
                String commandLine = sc.next();
                System.out.println("command:" + commandLine);
                if(commandLine.equals("d") && !hasDimension)
                {
                    System.out.println("checkPoint! " + commandToken);
                    setDimension(commandToken);
                    hasDimension = true;
                }
                else if(commandLine.equals("b") && !hasDefaultCell)
                {
                    System.out.println("checkPoint! " + commandToken);
                    setDefaultCell(commandToken);
                    hasDefaultCell = true;
                }
                else if(hasDimension && hasDefaultCell)
                {
                    char command = commandToken.charAt(0);
                    System.out.println("checkPoint! " + commandToken);
                    switch(command)
                    {
                        case 'e':
                        erase(commandToken);
                        break;
                        case 'x':
                        ANSI.cls();
                        break;
                        default:
                        processShape(commandToken);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                commandToken = parser.nextLine();
            }
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            if(e.getMessage().equals("p"))
            {
                System.out.println( "\nPlot - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException\n\n" );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "\nError reading input file: " + args[0] );
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println( "\nError reading input file(from main): " + args[0]);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) 
        {
            throw e;
        }
        ANSI.cls();
        map.printMap();
        System.out.println("Dimensions(map): " + map.getWidth() + " x " + map.getHeight());
    }

    private static void processShape(String command)
    {
        Scanner parser = new Scanner(command);
        String name = parser.next();
        int x = parser.nextInt();
        int y = parser.nextInt();
        String o = parser.next();
        parser.close();
        System.out.println("Shape Name: "+ name);
        System.out.println("Location: " + x + " , " + y);
        System.out.println("Dimensions(Map > pre-shape-proc): " + map.getWidth() + " x " + map.getHeight());
        bitMap b = new bitMap(map.getWidth(),map.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Dimensions(Map > pre-shape-proc): " + b.getWidth() + " x " + b.getHeight());
        shape s = new shape(name);
        
        System.out.println("Dimensions(map > after-shape-creation): " + map.getWidth() + " x " + map.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Dimensions(Map > after): " + b.getWidth() + " x " + b.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Shape Dimension: " + s.getWidth() + " x " + s.getHeight());
        map.addShape(x,y,s);
    }

    private static void setDefaultCell(String command)
    {
        Scanner parser = new Scanner(command);
        parser.next();
        String token = parser.next();
        char c;
        if(token.equals("space"))
        {
            c = ' ';
        }
        else
        {
            c = token.charAt(0);
        }
        int fg = ANSI.color2Int(parser.next());
        int bg = ANSI.color2Int(parser.next());
        parser.close();
        pixelCell cell = new pixelCell(c,fg,bg);
        map.setDefaultCell(cell);
        map.clearMap(map.getDefaultCell());
        System.out.println("Default Cell: " + map.getDefaultCell());
    }

    private static void setDimension(String command)
    {
        Scanner parser = new Scanner(command);
        System.out.println("command: " + command);
        parser.next();
        int w = parser.nextInt();
        int h = parser.nextInt();
        map = new bitMap(w,h);
        System.out.println("Dimensions: " + map.getWidth() + " x " + map.getHeight());
    }

    public static void erase(String command)
    {
        Scanner parser = new Scanner(command);
        parser.next();
        char c = parser.next().charAt(0);
        int fg = ANSI.color2Int(parser.next());
        int bg = ANSI.color2Int(parser.next());
        parser.close();
        pixelCell cell = new pixelCell(c,fg,bg);
        map.clearMap(cell);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `main`-method?

Comment: Your `pixelGrid` contructor re-initializes the `static` attribute .`defaultCell` and so the second instantiation of the classs "resets" all values. (same for `bitMap` with the second ctor)

Comment: @tomse does that mean that `static` variables are not created for each derivation of the class?  or did I misunderstood?

Comment: @DavidLuk No they exist once per class - no matter how much other classes are derived from this class. Furthermore your problem will occur even if you create two instances of the same derived class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `pixelGrid` contructor re-initializes the static attribute `defaultCell` and so the second instantiation of the class (or one of its derived classes) "resets" all values.

```
public class pixelGrid
{
  private static pixelCell defaultCell;

  public pixelGrid()
  {
    // resets defaultCell
    defaultCell = new pixelCell();
  }
}
```

Instead you should eiter initialize the `static` attribute directly:

```
private static pixelCell defaultCell = new pixelCell();
```

Or make use of a static initialization block (mainly if there is more to do than just the one `new`)

```
private static pixelCell defaultCell;

static {
  defaultCell = new pixelCell();
}
```

(If you need the `static` attribute once per derived class you have to declare it in the derived classes separately.)

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html